# Python packages to create a word graph?

Tags: python, graph, statistics, visualization, data-visualization

What python packages are available for creating word graphs? The things where the most popular words in your dataset are bigger.

Please suggest a package other than matplotlib if possible, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't tried it myself but seen good results from the [word_cloud](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud) python package - looks like it's being actively developed, documentation is ok, and can easily be installed with `pip install wordcloud`.